# sensorManager.unregisterListener = disable the sensors? - android

Tags: android, performance, android-sensors, battery

May I ask is it true that after the following snippet, the sensors are all disabled, i.e. STOP working completely?

```
protected void onPause() {
    // unregister listener
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

I am building up an app and battery life is a big concern. I am not sure what exactly

```
sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
```

means? My understanding is that as its name suggests, this statement only unregisters the LISTENER. That is, no one will listen.

But I think it does NOT mean that the sensors actually really stop. I guess it is just the sensors still keep working, and the difference is that now no one is listening now.

**If true, how to disable the sensors COMPLETELY so as to save power?**

**Is that single unregister statement enough?**

Comment: This is the correct method, and removes your interest in sensor events. You don't disable the sensors any more than you would start them when you register. These are common services used across the whole os, just because your not interested in them doesn't mean no other app is.

Comment: @LionelPort  makes sense. So no need and impossible to disable them right?